# VS code Typescript hints - auto add?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've just started using Typescript, in VS code, when I type something like

```
  let s = "string" 
  // do something with s
```

VS code suggests `:string` next to the s variable in light grey which is nice

```
  let s : string = "string"
```

Is there a way to auto-add the `: string` part without having to manually type it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're describing is [Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html).

Typescript does a pretty good job of knowing your data types, especially if it's something simple, like a number or a string. You can decide for yourself how much or how little you want to use inference, but it's good to be consistent with your approach throughout the project.

Personally, I don't type my variables within functions, unless the compiler complains about it for some reason. I will add types to my parameters and return values, and that's mostly about it. More commonly, I find myself needing to use [Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) when working with DOM elements.